# why ping always succeeds and never fails?

Tags: windows-10, ping

Whenever there is a network problem, my colleagues always say "try ping"

Honestly, I have never seen ping fails. It always "succeeds" even when there is no network whatsoever. Right now I am having a problem with a network with two computers and still "ping" ing the other computer gives "success" (even with no cable whatsoever

What can be wrong with ping?

The results are **always** this (forgive me but the results are in a foreign language, so I will try to translate)

```
>ping <address of other PC>

Ping is sent to <address of other PC> 32 bytes of data:
Response from <address of other PC>: Byte count = 32 hours <1 ms TTL = 128
Response from <address of other PC>: Byte count = 32 hours <1 ms TTL = 128
Response from <address of other PC>: Byte count = 32 hours <1 ms TTL = 128
Response from <address of other PC>: Byte count = 32 hours <1 ms TTL = 128

Ping statistics of <address of other PC>:
     Number of packets: transmission = 4, reception = 4, loss = 0 (loss of 0%),
Approximate round trip time (ms):
     Minimum = 0 ms, maximum = 0 ms, average = 0 ms
```

EDIT: "It is not clear what I am asking"

I am asking Why does ping never works? (Since it always replies with success no matter what)

Comment: There is something intercepting ICMP Ping and returning fake results.

Comment: Are you pinging the localhost?

Comment: No, I am pinging the ip address of the other computer (connected by cross cable).

Comment: It's only a "success" if the reply address is from the machine you actually pinged.  A network adaptor or gateway replying that a host is unreachable is not a "success". Without details showig outputs of ping succeeding in all cases it is impossible to know what your actual problem is and what is considered a "success".

Comment: @Mokubai I added details of the response

Comment: @KansaiRobot is <address> the same as <address of other PC>? Ping often shows replies from different addresses such as your gateway machine which is *technically* a success... your edit is unclear still as you've not addressed my point that the received address is important. Use example addresses if you have to, but at least show whether it is different to the address you are trying to ping.

Comment: You also need to provide details of your system as this could well be dependant on whether you are using Windows, Linux, or MacOS. What version would be a good shout too.

Comment: This really sounds like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and it's unclear as well. Please specify your scenario properly.

Comment: It seems you're using Windows (PC). You could try using *ipconfig /flushdns*, *arp -d <ip address of other computer>*, and pinging it again. If it still responds, then *arp -a* after the ping to see what MAC address it thinks the "other" IP address is associated with.